# Getting "no groovy library is defined for module" on a maven project when compiling the project from Intellij

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, junit

Below is the pom.xml content. I generated the project with maven archetype quickstart with junit. I encounter two problems:

1. When trying to run tests from Intellij, I get "no Groovy library defined", although I have nothing to do with Groovy in this project.
2. When doing mvn test from command line, no tests are identified.

To mention, the default java version is 8 on my mac, so when running mvn i export JAVA_HOME to 12, maybe it's related to the problem nr.1, not sure.

```
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>12</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>12</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.pcollections</groupId>
            <artifactId>pcollections</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

Comment: Please file a bug with the sample project at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When trying to run tests from Intellij, I get "no Groovy library defined", although I have nothing to do with Groovy in this project.

This sound like a bug, since both pcollections and junit are not related to groovy:

Try to re-import your project (maven tab + reimport). If this doesn't help, close the project, and open up again the `pom.xml` it will offer to re-create the project and discard old data, agree to this and it will rebuild everything.

> When doing mvn test from command line, no tests are identified.

Probably the tests that you've developed do not follow the surefire convention for classes resolution (It should end with `*Test` although if I remember correctly it has changed slightly in the latest versions of surefire, so now, also `*Tests` is ok). Please add the maven command line output when it runs the "test" phase as well as one of your test definitions (even with a trivial test code).